# Test all elements of a vector of n elements simultaneously

Tags: c++

Can I test all elements of a vector of n elements simultaneously without test each element manually?

Something like that:

```
if( (v[0] == 1) && .. && (v[n] == 1)){
    //doSomething
}
```

Comment: If you have a magic processor that does `O(n)` things in one time step, then yes. If you have `O(1)` x86 processors like the rest of us plebs have, then no, you need to take `O(n)` time and use a little for loop.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Or you can use a standard library algorithm, which you can easily drop-in a parallized version of the algorithm later if necessary.

Comment: Sure but the standard version is just a for loop also.

Comment: @ChrisBeck If it's a parallized function, it's probably more than "just a for loop".

Comment: @NeilKirk: you're still talking O(n).

Comment: It's ambiguous whether "simultaneously" and "manually" refers to algorithmic complexity or typing/coding convenience

Comment: @NeilKirk i just don't want write test by test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, you can use an algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

if (std::all_of(begin(v), end(v), [](auto n){ return n == 1; })) {
    // do something
}
```

If your vendor implements the [Technical Specification for Parallelism Extensions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism/existing), you have access to a parallelized version of this algorithm.